# 1つのソースを複数人で作り始める場合のTIPS

Tags: git, gitlab

例えば、複数のアクションから成る1つのコントローラを、アクションごとに複数の担当者で作成する場合、
どのようにすればできるだけ衝突を起こさず作成ができるでしょうか。

コントローラはファイルが無い状態から作り始めます。

Comment: `git` タグが付いていますが、git の利用が前提の質問ということでしょうか？

Comment: 「アクション」や「コントローラ」に触れられていますが、何か特定のフレームワークを念頭に置かれているのであれば、それを明示した方がヒントが得られるかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick すみません、gitを想定した質問でした。確かに質問文にはっきりと書いてありませんね。気を付けます。

Comment: @sayuri 多人数が同時に編集するケースとして、一般的なフレームワークを用いた開発をイメージしました。具体的には現在PHP(Laravel)をしており、衝突が多く発生したことから、一般的なサクセスパターンをお聞きしたく、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 4):

> 1つのコントローラを、アクションごとに複数の担当者で作成する場合、
>   どのようにすればできるだけ衝突を起こさず作成ができるでしょうか。

- コントローラー層を 業務ロジックライブラリを呼び出すだけの軽い実装とする
- 業務ロジックのライブラリは UNIT テストを必ず書く
- 他の人の開発資産をマージした時には 必ず UNIT テストが OK となることを確認する。

をするだけで、`git` は 同一行を 複数の人が修正しない限り 自動的マージが 衝突せず、かなり
うまくマージしてくれます。
ごくまれに、変なマージをすることがあるので、それを UNIT テストで 検出できるようにしておきます。

あとは

- git の コミットの粒度に気を付ける

も 大事だと思います。
初版の コードがどんどん追加されている時にはあまり衝突が発生せず 自動マージで結構 自動で解決
する事が多いのですが、
開発が 中盤から終盤に差し掛かった時に リファクタリングが 機能修正、機能追加が発生します。
このタイミングでの衝突は 解決の難易度が上がります。

この時に役立つのは `わかりやすいコミットメッセージ`と `1つのコミットに いろいろ詰め込まない事`
です。

よくあることなのですが、
バグ修正していたら、他のバグを見つけたので一緒に修正したとか
バグ修正中に コメントのタイプミスを見つけたので 他の場所も一緒に修正した
とかやってしまいがちですが ここは 我慢して 修正のコミットと タイプミスのコミットは
分けるべきだと思います。

[Git によるデバッグ](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%96%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-Git-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E3%83%87%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0)

にある `二分探索` の部分の例のように 何かがおかしくなった時に
『問題が混入した コミットを 特定する』
という事ができるので、読んでおいていざというときに試してみてください。

### 他のブランチ戦略について

git の場合には `git flow` とか `pull リクエスト` 等の 開発ワークフローに
沿って開発するという 戦略もあります。

機能単位に独立した物を ブランチ間で マージしたり、
バグの修正依頼を pull リクエストでマージしたりする方法ですが

複数の開発者で同じようなコードを同時に開発する場合には、むいていないような気がします。
それぞれの開発者は 同じブランチで こまめに commit と pull と push を行って ソースコードの
差分が小さい状態で開発した方がいいと思います。

チームが大きくなって全然別の機能を作っているチームが別にあるならそのチームは別ブランチで開発
定期的にブランチ間のマージを行う方がいいと思います。

細かな運用は そのチームによってさまざまなのでしょうが、参考までに・・。

Comment: ありがとうございます、とても参考になりました。

現在、機能単位ごとにPULLリクエストを発行してソースレビューを行っていますが、それぞれの開発者は 同じブランチで こまめに commit と pull と push を行うと言った流れで開発する場合、どういったタイミング、単位でレビューするのが望ましいでしょうか？

Comment: ネットを検索したら https://moneyforward.com/engineers_blog/2015/11/30/reviewable-commit-log/ や https://qiita.com/ikuwow/items/fb52a54c086398eb5b92 がありました。 参考にしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。参考にいたします。